# gem annotate not working after migrating from rvm to rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was able to install annotate by doing `sudo gem install annotate` (I had to use sudo because of permission denied). It appears to have installed but I get error when running. I think the problem could be related to uninstalling rvm. (Now using rbenv). When I installed rvm I removed the ~/.rvm folder and removed references in .bash_profile

Unable to install annotate as regular user

```
Chris-Muenchs-MacBook-Air:wifiwaiters cmuench$ gem install annotate
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/cmuench/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/annotate-2.6.5/AUTHORS.rdoc
Chris-Muenchs-MacBook-Air:wifiwaiters cmuench$
```

Able to install via sudo

```
Chris-Muenchs-MacBook-Air:wifiwaiters cmuench$ sudo gem install annotate
Successfully installed annotate-2.6.5
Parsing documentation for annotate-2.6.5
Done installing documentation for annotate after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

SUDO

```
Chris-Muenchs-MacBook-Air:wifiwaiters cmuench$ sudo annotate
/Users/cmuench/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'annotate' (>= 0) among 54 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/cmuench/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/cmuench/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
    from /Users/cmuench/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/annotate:22:in `<main>'
```

NON SUDO

```
Chris-Muenchs-MacBook-Air:wifiwaiters cmuench$ annotate
/Users/cmuench/Desktop/WifiWaiters-Repos/wifiwaiters/Gemfile:24:in `evaluate': compile error (SyntaxError)
/Users/cmuench/Desktop/WifiWaiters-Repos/wifiwaiters/Gemfile:24: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
                                       ^
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:136:in `definition'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:124:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/setup.rb:6
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/cmuench/Desktop/WifiWaiters-Repos/wifiwaiters/config/boot.rb:4
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/cmuench/Desktop/WifiWaiters-Repos/wifiwaiters/config/application.rb:1
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from ./Rakefile:4
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/annotate-2.4.0/lib/annotate.rb:17:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/annotate-2.4.0/lib/annotate.rb:17:in `load_tasks'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/annotate-2.4.0/bin/annotate:66
    from /usr/bin/annotate:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/annotate:19
Chris-Muenchs-MacBook-Air:wifiwaiters cmuench$
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by doing:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 ~/.rbenv
```

Now I don't need to use sudo to install gems and run them